# Excel VBA - Trying to Copy 300 Workbook Ranges into a Sheet Based on a Batch File List and Receiving "Pastespecial method of range class failed" Error

Tags: vba

I have my code working as shown below but depending on the number of workbooks I am running into an error `Pastespecial method of range class failed`.  The error has happened anywhere from 3 workbooks importing to the highest I've gotten in tests so far is 240/300.  It started pretty but I'm having the best luck currently with the large selection of repetitive code outlined below.

Here are some key components of what I am doing:

1. In the combination worksheet, macro button exists on the 'Inputs' tab
2. 'Inputs' tab has specified ranges of where the specific worksheet is to be copied onto worksheet 'data1'
3. 'calc_page' has a list of import paths that may change based on what folder the workbook is located in.  They reference the associated workbook paths that I would like to import into the ranges specified in component 2

Here are the primary steps I want to accomplish:

1. Open workbook, copy a specific range from that workbook reference with an indirect
2. Paste that workbook data in a specified range on the 'data1' worksheet [this changes depending on what range I have in the list]
3. Clear the clipboard and Quit the workbook
4. Start process for the next file in the range

I have tried multiple scenarios on stackoverflow with similar results.

Since this is a long process, I am calling a list of other macros set up in a similar fashion.  I have shortened the code up below, but each macro has about 45 of the directly coded references.

```
Sub ImportDataFromList()
    Dim App As New Excel.Application 'create new hidden Excel window

    ' Assign active sheet for copying
    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Set wsActive = Sheets("data1")

    'Open designated file in new Excel window as read only
    Dim wbImport As Workbook

    Set wbImport = App.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Worksheets("calc_page").Range("C5"), UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wsActive = Sheets("data1")
    'Copy the data to active sheet
    wbImport.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:N125").Copy
    wsActive.Range([indirect("P5")]).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  
    App.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears clipboard
    wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=False 'Close new Excel window without saving
    App.Quit 'Quit new Excel window

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))


    Set wbImport = App.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Worksheets("calc_page").Range("C6"), UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wsActive = Sheets("data1")
    'Copy the data to active sheet
    wbImport.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AJ74").Copy
    wsActive.Range([indirect("P6")]).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  
    App.CutCopyMode = False 'Clears clipboard
    wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=False 'Close new Excel window without saving
    App.Quit 'Quit new Excel window

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
End Sub
```

I want it to be able to run from end-to-end without the pastespecial error and successfully import all the plaintext values from this list of workbooks.  Really appreciate any guidance or even potential ideas on how I may get this to work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Could not be able to understand why New Excel application is used for opening the source files. Setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` could easily be used to make source file virtually invisible. Purpose of Application Wait is also unclear.

Tried several times with the modified code for 300 loops and range of around 250 X 15 cells data (with repeating opening & closing only one source file for trial purpose) and take only about 3 minutes for completing the task successfully.

```
Sub ImportDataFromList()
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim wbImport As Workbook
Dim wsCalc As Worksheet
Dim Fname As String, Rw As Long, sSht As String, sRng As String, Trng As String
Dim srcRng As Range, TrgRng As Range
'Dim Tm As Double

Set wsActive = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data1")
Set wsCalc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc_page")
'Tm = MicroTimer()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Rw = 5 To 305
Fname = wsCalc.Range("C" & Rw) ' Source File Name4
sSht = wsCalc.Range("D" & Rw)  ' Source Sheet name
sRng = wsCalc.Range("E" & Rw)  ' Source Range
Trng = wsCalc.Range("F" & Rw)  ' Target Range.(Only Top Left cell address is used for trial. later resized to the source range)

Set wbImport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Fname, UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True)
Set srcRng = wbImport.Worksheets(sSht).Range(sRng)
Set TrgRng = wsActive.Range(Trng)
Set TrgRng = TrgRng.Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count)
TrgRng.Cells.Value = srcRng.Cells.Value
wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next

'Tm = MicroTimer() - Tm
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Debug.Print Tm
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Ahmed, I want to thank you so much for your help.  It worked and I am now quite the happy person.  I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Thanks. You also made my day.

Comment: Glad to hear that Ahmed!